# Identifying and correcting typos in a data set using subset

Tags: r, subset, data-cleaning, levels

I have a data set: (can be seen from the below link)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avMDIxYmZLSnRfUDA/view?usp=sharing and I want to make data correction using subset & levels function. Here is what I have been trying to apply  but it does not seem to work:

```
# Setting working directory
setwd("F:/Intro Data Science/Assignment Part B/Assignment Part B-20170902")
plot.new()
options(digits=2)

# Reading data set
installed.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

# Reading data set
power <- read.csv("data set 6.csv", na.strings="")

# SUBSETTING
Area <- as.numeric(power$Area)
City <- as.character(power$City)
P.Winter <- as.numeric(power$P.Winter)
P.Summer <- as.numeric(power$P.Summer)

#Data Cleaning
levels(power$City)<- c(levels(power$City),"Auckland")
power$City[power$City == "Ackland"] <- "Auckland"
```

I really need your help guys. This was supposed to be easy because I have followed exactly what was given in the lecture but it doesn't do anything when I run the code.
Appreciate your help
Nelson

The output requested:

```
> dput(head(power, 30))
structure(list(Area = c(144.38, 176.83, 268.71, 208.67, 123.61, 
199.3, 109.46, 183.28, 110.61, 146.91, 77.451, 232.65, 270.94, 
49.191, 234.5, 280.93, 192.18, 95.918, 230.74, 72.698, 129.26, 
110.76, 199.44, 129.75, 146.8, 287.97, 162.1, 249.03, 159.3, 
272.51), City = c("Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", 
"Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", 
"Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", 
"Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Ackland ", "Auckland ", 
"Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", 
"Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", "Auckland ", 
"Auckland "), P.Winter = c(1684.9, 1926.7, 2026.9, 1938.1, 1579.9, 
1991.4, 1572.5, 1691.2, 1684.2, 1743.6, 1234.6, 2043, 1986.7, 
1259.7, 1870.4, 2115.6, 18000, 1452, 1936.2, 1430.2, 1587.3, 
1614.3, 1993.2, 1746.4, 1807.6, 2009.4, 1859.1, 1985.5, 1909.4, 
1892.7), P.Summer = c(1194.5, 1487.3, 1737.3, -158, 1148.1, 1445.8, 
885.77, 1393, 1191.5, 1149.9, 813.38, 1623.8, 1708, 874.48, 1635.7, 
1826.1, 1596.6, 793.71, 1668.8, 905.6, 1227.3, 938.38, 1523.1, 
1012.6, 1122.8, 1829.5, 1223.3, 1653.2, 1175.5, 1882)), .Names = c("Area", 
"City", "P.Winter", "P.Summer"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the function you want is `droplevels`.
First, make up some data.

```
set.seed(5295)    # make the results reproducible
cities <- factor(sample(c("Ackland", "Auckland", "Wellington", "Sidney"), 100, TRUE))
power <- data.frame(City = cities)
```

Now the code, starting with yours.

```
power$City[power$City == "Ackland"] <- "Auckland"
power$City <- droplevels(power$City)

levels(power$City)    # check if it worked
#[1] "Auckland"   "Sidney"     "Wellington"
```

**EDIT.**
After seen the output of `dput(head(power, 30))`, the solution became onvious. The column `City` is of class `character`, not `factor`, and there are no values `"Ackland"` or `"Auckland"`, they have a trailing white space that is messing things up. So all we need to do is to remove `"Ackland "` and remove the trailing white spaces.

```
str(power)
#'data.frame':   30 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ Area    : num  144 177 269 209 124 ...
# $ City    : chr  "Auckland " "Auckland " "Auckland " "Auckland " ...
# $ P.Winter: num  1685 1927 2027 1938 1580 ...
# $ P.Summer: num  1194 1487 1737 -158 1148 ...

which(power$City == "Ackland ")    # note the white space
#[1] 18

which(power$City == "Auckland ")    # note the white space
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
#[26] 27 28 29 30

# remove the value "Ackland ", with white space
power$City[power$City == "Ackland "] <- "Auckland"
power$City <- trimws(power$City)    # remove white spaces from all of them
```

And no columns vanish, just run `str(power)` to see it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I want is just to correct the missed spelled word in the column, like "Ackland" to "Auckland".

Comment: @Nelson But if you don't drop the factor level it will still be there though no longer used. That's why the call to `droplevels` is important.

Comment: But it does not do what I expect. The code you provided made all other columns dissapeared and I did not change the misspelled word which "Ackland" to "Auckland". What I want is just to correct that word and keep other information too.

Comment: @Nelson I cannot understand how the code above can make other columns dispear or not change the word `"Ackland"` to `"Auckland"`. Can you edit the question and instead of a graphic image of the data post the output of `dput(head(power, 30))`?

Comment: `> dput(head(power, 30))
structure(list(City = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Auckland", "Sydney", 
"Wellington"), class = "factor")), .Names = "City", row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: It excludes all other columns and only showed the column of the "City". It does change the word Ackland -> Auckland though but I will need the data to be intact

Comment: @Nelson You didn't understand me. After `power <- read.csv("data set 6.csv", na.strings="")` post the output of `dput(head(power, 30))` in the *question* not as a comment. This is because we don't have access to the file, and like this we can see an exact copy of its first 30 rows.

Comment: please double check in the question. I also included a link in the question on the first sentence for an access to the whole data set

Comment: @Nelson OK, thanks. I think this is it. It would have been impossible to guess what's going on with your data without seeing the real structure of the data as output by `dput`.